# Angular universal throwing "Error at XMLHttpRequest.send"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal, angular10

I recently upgraded the project to Angular 10 and added angular universal. There are no issues in building the application but when I run my application on the development environment it throws me the following error

> ERROR Error
> at XMLHttpRequest.send (/Users/user/Documents/Web Projects/Freelance/my-project/dist/frontend/server/main.js:297667:19)

I am using the following command to run the application

> npm run dev:ssr

I have checked isPlatformBrowser in guards too but still, no luck.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help anyone in the future. Making interceptor to handle HTTP calls solved the problem. In my case, all external APIs calls were with the absolute URL. Interceptor helped me checks if the URL is relative or absolute, and updates the URL if necessary.

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Request} from 'express';
import {REQUEST} from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

@Injectable()
export class UniversalInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) protected request: Request) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    let serverReq: HttpRequest<any> = req;
    if (this.request && req.url.indexOf('http') !== 0) {
      let newUrl = `${this.request.protocol}://${this.request.get('host')}`;
      if (!req.url.startsWith('/')) {
        newUrl += '/';
      }
      newUrl += req.url;
      serverReq = req.clone({url: newUrl});
    }

    return next.handle(serverReq);
  }
}
```

Comment: Was this included in your add.module providers or your app.server.module providers?